# SQL query to get a sum for each day between two dates

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to view the sum of rewards for a specific name between two dates

This is MyTable

```
|   NAME    |  REWARD   |    DATE      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|   Chris   |    yes    |  05.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    yes    |  05.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    no     |  07.05.2018  |
|   John    |    yes    |  10.05.2018  |
```

Let's say the name I am looking for is "Chris" and the date is between 04.05.2018 - 08.05.2018. The query should also count the REWARD="yes" fields for each day and add the amount value "0" for days when no reward was earned.

Then this should be the result:

```
|   NAME    |  AMOUNT   |    DATE      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|   Chris   |    0      |  04.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    2      |  05.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    0      |  06.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    0      |  07.05.2018  |
|   Chris   |    0      |  08.05.2018  |
```

I am using Firebird 2.5

I tried this query, but the missing dates with "0" amount are not generated when doing it this way

```
SELECT name, SUM(CASE WHEN reward='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AMOUNT, DATE
  from MyTable 
  WHERE DATE between '04.05.2018' and '08.05.2018'  
    AND NAME='Chris' 
  GROUP BY NAME, DATE
```

Comment: Are you looking for a query here or a stored proc with parameters you will use to pass in name and date range?

Comment: Three times in a row you have asked a question laying out your requirements, expecting us to do your work for you. Please first try to do the work yourself, and if you can't get it to work, then at least post what you tried yourself and describe how it doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: it doesn't matter... each of them would be ok

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wouldn't post a question without trying to solve it by myself for hours

Comment: @Chris You'd be surprised how many people do post a question without even trying, and it is impossible to discern which type a poster is. Posting what you tried gives us information about what you're asking and also an indication that you aren't just trying to make us do your work, it also allows an answer to address why your solution doesn't, which can add more value.

Comment: In any case, I can think of three or four different solutions. I'll try to post them tomorrow or this weekend, I don't have the time now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks...I'm looking forward for your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main difficulty is that you want to have rows for dates for which there is no data in the table. So you have to find a way to generate these rows with zero values.

I think simplest, easiest to understand, solution would be an selectable stored procedure, ie

```
CREATE PROCEDURE damounts(d1 date, d2 date, name varchar(20)) 
RETURNS (d date, amount integer)
AS 
BEGIN
  d = d1;
  while(d <= d2)do begin
     amount = (select sum(case when Reward = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) from test where d = :d and name = :name);
     if (amount is null) then amount = 0;
     suspend;
     d = d + 1;
  end
END
```

and to use it you just select from it:

```
select * from damounts('2018-05-04', '2018-05-10', 'Chris')
```

If you want to do without SP then Firebird 2.5 supports recursive CTE which can be used to generate all dates for given range. Use another CTE to calculate sums for dates for which there is data and then join them by date:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  select cast('2018-05-04' as date) d from rdb$database
  UNION ALL
  select d+1 from dates where d < '2018-05-10'
)
,
sums (d, dsum) AS (
  select
    d,
    sum(case when Reward = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS amount
  from test
  where name = 'Chris' and d >= '2018-05-04' and d <= '2018-05-10'
  group by d
)
select
  'Chris' as name,
  d.d as "date",
  coalesce(s.dsum, 0) as amount
from dates d
left join sums s on(s.d = d.d);
```

Note that in the examples I used column name `d` instead of `date` as one can't have column named `date` in Firebird unless using quoted identifiers (which I never do). Instead of your `MyTable` I used table name `test`.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions I can think of are:

## Selectable stored procedure to do all the work

Already shown in the [answer by ain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400362/466862)

## Using a recursive common table expression to generate the dates

This solution is similar to the one provided by ain, but with only one CTE, and using `count` instead of `sum`:

```
with recursive dates as (
  select date'2018-05-04' as rewarddate 
  from rdb$database
  union all
  select rewarddate + 1 
  from dates 
  where rewarddate < date'2018-05-08'
)
select 
  'Chris' as name, 
  d.rewarddate, 
  count(case when g.reward = 'yes' then 1 end) as amount
from dates d 
left join MyTable g 
  on d.rewarddate = g."DATE" and g.name = 'Chris'
group by d.rewarddate
```

## Selectable stored procedure for the date range

```
set term #;
recreate procedure daterange(startdate date, enddate date) 
    returns (dateval date)
as
begin
  dateval = startdate;
  while (dateval <= enddate) do
  begin
    -- output row
    suspend;
    dateval = dateval + 1;
  end
end#
set term ;#
```

This selectable stored procedure produces a range of dates from `startdate` to `enddate` (inclusive).

We can then use this in a similar way as the solution with the CTE:

```
select 
  'Chris' as name, 
  r.dateval, 
  count(case when g.reward = 'yes' then 1 end) as amount
from daterange(date'2018-05-04', date'2018-05-08') r
left join MyTable g 
  on r.dateval = g."DATE" and g.name = 'Chris'
group by r.dateval
```

## Rethink your database design

A number of (potential) problems I see with the current design

1. Needing to explicitly specify the name as `'Chris' as name` in the select list limits the flexibility (eg you can't directly use this solution to get a list for both Chris and John as a single query result)
2. The repeated presence of the same name in `MyTable` suggests that you need to maintain a separate table of persons (this would also simplify solving 1)
3. The fact that dates without 'rewards' are important, seems to indicate that maybe you need to maintain a table of dates; this would also allow for gaps (eg if weekends or holidays should be excluded). Doing this has its downsides (eg having to populate and maintain dates, can have its own maintenance overhead)
4. The fact that Chris was given multiple rewards on the same date, may indicate that reward itself should also be a table (but only if this is significant information), or that `MyTable` needs additional information why or what was rewarded.
5. The fact you register that Chris was not rewarded on one date, but not on others suggests that maybe you should only register something was rewarded, not when it wasn't rewarded. This removes the need to have a `reward` column. Alternatively, if the fact that Chris was not rewarded something on the 7th of May is significant, that may mean you need additional columns with the why.

For example, an alternative design could be something like:

With a table `person`

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   id integer generated by default as identity constraint pk_person primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null -- may need a unique constraint as well
);
```

Populated as:

```
id  name
1   Chris
2   John
```

And `relevantdate` (I can't come up with a better name for lack of context)

```
create table relevantdate (
   dateval date constraint pk_relevantdate primary key
);
```

Populated with dates between 2018-05-04 and 2018-05-12 (hint: use a `insert into .. select ..` using the `daterange` procedure created above).

You can then change the design of `MyTable` (renamed to `reward` here) to:

```
create table reward (
  id integer generated by default as identity constraint pk_reward primary key,
  personid integer not null constraint fk_reward_person references person(id),
  rewarddate date not null constraint fk_reward_relevantdate references relevantdate(dateval)
  -- maybe add some more columns with information on why/what
)
```

Populated as (leaving of id as it is not relevant):

```
personid  rewarddate
1         2018-05-05
1         2018-05-05
2         2018-05-10
```

For greater flexibility, it is worth to consider not defining the foreign key `fk_reward_relevantdate`. This would allow to insert rewards on dates not in the `relevantdate` table. In that case the `relevantdate` table only functions as a supporting object for reporting purposes.

As a select you can now use something like:

```
select
  p.name,
  rd.dateval,
  count(r.rewarddate)
from person p
cross join relevantdate rd
left join reward r
  on p.id = r.personid and rd.dateval = r.rewarddate
where rd.dateval between date'2018-05-04' and date'2018-05-08'
and p.name = 'Chris'
group by rd.dateval, p.name
```

Leave off the `p.name = 'Chris'` condition, and now you get the information for both Chris and John.

Note: I have used `generated by default as identity`, which is a Firebird 3 feature. It is not really necessary for this example. The equivalent in Firebird 2.5 and earlier would require a sequence + trigger to generate an id, but in these examples, you can simply leave out the entire `generated by default as identity`, and in the case of the `reward` table, you can consider leaving the `id` column off entirely.